# Not getting query string if trailing slash is not present when deployed

Tags: vue.js, url, gridsome

I've to read the query parameters from an URL in my **Gridsome** app
. I have 2 cases of URL, in one of which my `query` key is coming empty object `{}` when accessing using `this.$route.query` in my app.

**case 1:** `https://app.com/forms/ads/?param1=one&param2=two` - There is a `/` slash just before query params starts.

**case 2:** `https://app.com/forms/ads?param1=one&param2=two` - No `/` slash just before query params.

When I'm access `this.$route.query` on my `localhost` both of these cases giving me the value of `param1` and `param2`.

My problem is when I'm pushing it to production, **case 2** is returning an empty object `{}`.

```
storeUtmData() {
  const utmSource = this.$route.query.utm_source;
  const utmMedium = this.$route.query.utm_medium;
  console.log(this.$route.query); // return {}
  ...
},
```

Answer (score 0):

case1 is requesting in an "index.html" in the folder "https://app.com/forms/ads/" while for case2 no resource will exist on static served webpage when you have build your project with gridsome for production (if you don't have any really special infrastructure).
As the resource doesn't exist my guess is that vue-router which you access with "this.$route" contains only an empty object with this case2.

Why does it work locally ?

I can imagine locally in the dev environment express treats the resource "ads" as a route while on live there is only a folder containing and index.html which is served by a webserver.
The difference between a route and a folder which is served statically by a webserver is that a route from an nodejs express application is actually triggering directly application logic to be executed, while the webserver is mainly transferring the static files in the folder. By convention a folder is accessed with a slash at the end in a URL.

For further information please read the following sections:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URL#Structure
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URL#Implementation

I hope that answers your question.

Why do you need case2 to work in production ?
It should be under your control how to link to certain URL at least within your application.

Cheers,
ewatch